# Buscar palabras clave en excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Necesito buscar palabras relacionadas con las columnas de arriba, y poner un "1" si hay en el texto.
Que codigo VBA podria usar o que formula?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ENTERO(NO(ESERROR(HALLAR(N$6;$G7))))
```

- [`HALLAR()`](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/hallar-y-hallarb-funciones-hallar-y-hallarb-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495) Te devuelve la posición de un texto dentro de otro, o `#VALOR!` si no lo encuentra.
- `NO(ESERROR(...))` lo convierte en verdadero/falso si lo encontró.
- `ENTERO(...)` convierte el verdadero/falso en 1/0.